# Azure IoT EdgeHub and C# IoT Hub SDK Version Compatibility

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

Is there a way to tell which versions of EdgeHub system module are compatible with versions of the C# Devices.Client IoT SDK?

In the [release notes for EdgeHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iotedge/releases) it mentions of updating the C# SDK if used, but the most recent release references SDK version: 1.20.3 which is a minor version behind the [current SDK release: 1.21.3](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/releases)

Is it safe to use the latest stable versions of both? If not is there a compatibility table somewhere to reference?

Answer (score 1):

The 1.0.9 RC (pre-release) version references version 1.21.3 of the SDK.

If your question is: can I use the most recent version of the Devices.Client SDK for my custom modules, my answer would be: yes.  Since your custom module is in fact a Docker Container, it runs as an isolated process and should not be affected by the version of that assembly that is in use by the edgeHub or edgeAgent modules.

Comment: Are the custom edge modules really isolated? Aren't the edge modules connecting to the Azure Hub via the EdgeHub? My understanding is that messages are just basically queued locally by the Client SDK call, and it is the EdgeHub that handles maintaining connectivity and sending the messages to the cloud end point when able to.